# how to store Specific Column in scope variable Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have `$scope.Profile` variable, in this variable below image data are store but i don't want yellow highlighted column , how to remove these columns from `$scope.Profile` variable, i want only full_name, Company_name, mobile_number, address for updation.
How do this please help me.

```
$scope.Profile = Auth.getCurrentUserSync();  // This variable have below image data,  
  $scope.updateProfile = function () {         
     $http.put(properties.customerupdate_path + "/"+Id,$scope.Profile).success(function (response) {             
        console.log('Inner alert');
        // window.location.href = '/customerprofile';
     });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <form ng-submit="updateProfile()" >
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Profile.full_name ' name='full_name' >
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Mobile Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Profile.mobile_number ' name='mobile_number'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Profile.company_name ' name='company_name'>
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Position</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='Profile.designation '  name='designation' class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false">
        </div>
    </div>
```

//how to store array values to json array they add only last array

```
     var arrayLength = $scope.Profile.addresses.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {   

        $scope.tempObject={full_name:$scope.Profile.full_name,
          mobile_number:$scope.Profile.mobile_number,
         company_name:$scope.Profile.company_name,
         designation: $scope.Profile.designation,    
    addresses: [{site_name: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].site_name,
      street_address: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].street_address,
      city: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].city,
      state: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].state,
      country: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].country,
      zip_code: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].zip_code,
      phone_number: $scope.Profile.addresses[i].phone_number
     }   

    ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new new object and add required properties to that object. copy value for properties from "profile" object to that object. Then assign that object to profile object.

```html
$scope.profile = {id:'1',full_name:'test'}; 
$scope.tempObject={full_name:$scope.profile.full_name};
$scope.profile=$scope.tempObject;
```

Comment: your right how to get address array please tell me @Anil

Answer (score 0):

```
function pick()
{
    var ret = new Object();
    for(i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
       ret[arguments[i]] = arguments[0][arguments[i]];

    return ret;
}
var updateObj =pick($scope.profile, 'full_name', 'Company_name', 'mobile_number', 'address');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.profile=
 [
  {
    "Name": "pravin",
    "phone": "23232",
    "address": [
      {
        "country": "india",
        "code": "4142411"        
      }
    ],
    "payementinfo": [
      {
        "type": "credit",
        "amount": "2541"    ,
        "bank":"SSI"    
      }
    ]
  }
]
  ;

 
  angular.forEach($scope.profile, function(obj) {
       $scope.Name=  obj.Name;
         $scope.phone=obj.phone;
         $scope.country=obj.address[0].country;
        $scope.type=obj.payementinfo[0].type;
   });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">  
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   Name: <b>{{Name}}</b><br/>
    phone: <b>{{phone}}</b><br/>
   country Name: <b>{{country}}</b><br/>
    type: <b>{{type}}</b><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```